# Perl HTML::TreeBuilder adding <html>, <head> and <body> tags to parsed content, how to stop or work around it?

Tags: html, perl, parsing, html-tree

Background:
I'm using HTML::TreeBuilder to parse an entire html page, say "whole_page" for reference's sake.  I'm then using the inherited parse_content method (same as for whole_page) of a new TreeBuilder object to to parse a chunk of html, say "html_to_insert".  The root element of html_to_insert should be a `<div>` tag.  Ultimately, the html_to_insert tree needs to be inserted into the the whole_page tree.

Problem:
The html_to_insert tree is being wrapped with `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags, which I obviously don't need.  I looked at HTML::Parser to see if there was a parameter that might solve the problem, but I couldn't find anything.

Question:
Is there a simple way to stop the parse method from wrapping html_to_insert with the un-needed tags?  Knowing what I'm trying to do, am I doing this ass backwards (is there a better way)?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look on `guts` method in [HTML::Tree](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder). It returns only non-implicit nodes as a list.

Answer (score 2):

If you can ensure your HTML is XHTML-compliant, that is, it's a proper XML document, you may be able to use XML tools to do the job instead.  In the past, I've used XML::Twig for this type of job, it was a bit easier that way.

Of course, if you're parsing arbitrary web pages from the internet, you may not have this type of guarantee.

Comment: of course XML::Twig will happily load HTML (using HTML::TreeBuilder or HTML::Tidy under the hood)... so you don't need any guarantee!

Comment: It's next to impossible to have valid HTML that's also valid XHTML. It can't have images, for starters, as IMG's end tag is forbidden for HTML and required for XHTML.